# Get data attribute from custom html result

Tags: django-autocomplete-light

Let's say I have a simple DAL `autocomplete` & `form` rendering custom html results, where **the result** contain data-attribute.

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

class CountryAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_result_label(self, item):
        return format_html('<span data-url="{}">{}</span>', item.get_dashboard_url(), item.name)


class CountryForm(forms.Form):
    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Country.objects.all(),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(
            url="country-autocomplete",
            attrs={
                "data-result-html": True,
            },
        ),
    )
```

Now on select I want to get the data attribute of the selected item.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id_country').on('select2:select', function(e) {
    // get the selected item data attributes.
  });
});
```

I've tried `$(this).find(":selected").data('url')`. But it returns `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

OK, after digging a little bit more I found two solutions which I'm gonna paste here in case someone else is having the same problem.

So the problem here is that `$(this).find(":selected")` returns the `option` but it has no data attributes because all the html is inside its `text` attribute (`$(this).find(":selected").text()` returns the markup.);

## Solution 1

So the first solution is do the following (I'm not sure what jQuery do behind the scenes here, it probably parse the markup and creates an object from it).

```
$($(this).find(":selected").text()).data('url')
```

## Solution 2

Another thing which I notice is that `$(this).find(":selected").data()` returns the data which `select2` gets from the ajax call. So we can alter our View to return more data.

```
class CountryAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    # ... get_result_label()
    def get_results(self, context):
        """Return data for the 'results' key of the response."""
        return [
            {
                "id": self.get_result_value(result),
                "text": self.get_result_label(result),
                "url": result.get_dashboard_url(),
                "selected_text": self.get_selected_result_label(result),
            }
            for result in context["object_list"]
        ]
```

And now in the Javascript we can go with:

```
$(this).find(":selected").data().data.url
```